# Apache Airflow : How to read a file from a specific worker?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am running an Airflow instance with 2 celery workers. I have a DAG which writes to a file `tmp/sample_file.txt` , where `tmp` is a folder placed in my airflow home and is present in all workers. Initially the file is blank.

My use case is, whatever I have written to `sample.txt` needs to be read in my next DAG. But what happens is the first DAG writes this file in only one worker whereas the other worker still has the same blank file. How can i make sure the DAG reads the file from the correct workers file system?

Comment: the fact whether a file is accessible to both workers depends on whether the file system is shared or not. is it shared? can you please confirm the same?